# Is the scaling of the imaginary part a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the following map from the complex plane `z` to `Z`:
$$  z = x+iy  \longrightarrow Z = x+iky $$

with $k$ a real value. Is this a conformal map? Such map would transform a circle into an ellipse for instance. Also, what would be the Jacobian of such transformation?
I guess it can be written $Z(z)= z + i (k-1) \sqrt{zz^*} \sin(\arg(z)))$ but I'm not sure how to derive this further.

Comment: Just check the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a conformal map preserves angles locally.  What does your map do to the angle between the real axis and a diagonal line?